# Translate a xib UI into storyboard

Tags: storyboard, swift3, macos-sierra

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    @IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "Warning"
        alert.informativeText = "Zombies approaching"
        alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.critical
        alert.showsSuppressionButton = true
        alert.suppressionButton!.title = "Stop scaring me"
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Ignore")
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Run")
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Panic")
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Do nothing")

        let handler = {(choice: NSModalResponse) -> Void in
            switch choice {
            case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
                print("Ignore")
            case NSAlertSecondButtonReturn:
                print("Run")
            case NSAlertThirdButtonReturn:
                print("Panic")
            case NSAlertThirdButtonReturn + 1:
                print("Do nothing")
            default:
                break
            }
            if alert.suppressionButton!.state == 1 {
                print("Checked.")
            } else {
                print("Not checked")
            }
        }
        alert.beginSheetModal(for: window, completionHandler: handler)
    }

}
```

All this is based on xib. I am wondering how to write the same UI with a storyboard? I could create a new view control and connect the button to it with a sheet segue, but I would lose all the ready-made goodies of NSAlert.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you just need to do the following:

1. Drag a new ViewController into the storyboard
2. File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Class (Subclass NSViewController)
3. Set the ViewController on your storyboard to this class (ie
   SomeViewController, or whatever name you chose in the previous step)
4. Drag a button onto the ViewController in the Storyboard
5. Ctrl+Drag the new Button into your SomeViewController.swift file to
   create an Action (not an outlet, select "Action" in the popover
   window)
6. Paste your alert code into there, it'll be called on press
7. Remove the `btn` function from your `AppDelegate`

Comment: Have already tried it before. The problem is `alert.beginSheetModal(for: window, completionHandler: handler)`. There is no `window` to be passed, you see?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this was for macOS. Try using `alert.runModal()` instead. Check out https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsalert/1535441-runmodal